# Moen Single-Handle (Monticello 7730) Cartridge replacement FAIL..what did I do wrong?

Tags: faucet, leaks, cartridge

UPDATE, MAY HAVE FIXED IT! Going to go get some plumber's grease and grease it up good before I do a full reassemble, but right now the water is no longer pouring out as it does in video above.

Fix: I pulled the cartridge out to try to really examine how it works and see if I could verify that it was pushed in all the way and I noticed that the o-ring on the bottom of the cartridge (stock pic, [image: hotlinked moen cartridge]) had a little chunk taken out of it. Thankfully, my old cartridge's bottom o-ring was intact (it was torn higher up on the big black section that has the hole in it) so I swapped the o-rings and then re-sat the cartridge in the hole, making sure it was seated completely.

(Original post)
I had a minor leak from base of kitchen sink faucet (the part that turns the faucet on and off, not the actual long-neck spout itself). Read up on it and it seemed that a faulty cartridge was the likely culprit. Bought new cartridge that matched the cartridge I pulled out of it. Did the replacement following directions I found online, which matched the directions that came in the new cartridge package (Moen 1225) I bought, and matched [this video](https://home-building.wonderhowto.com/how-to/fix-faucet-leaking-from-around-handle-307917/).

You can see that at about 4 min in the video, he turns the water back on and pulls up the cartridge to verify that he has his hot/cold settings correct.

Well, when I do that, water pours out of the top of the cartridge and goes EVERYWHERE...

Here's [a video](https://youtu.be/wHEXPRBUs_0) of what I mean.

Where did I screw this up? And how do I fix it?

I should mention that when this happened initially I tried putting the old cartridge back in to see if it would go back to the minor leak instead of pouring out water---but the old cartridge now behaves the same way as the new one does... so I'm inclined to think this is user error and not a bad cartridge..

Comment: you must be missing an o-ring or some sort of a seal

Comment: google `moen single handle cartridge images` ... when you find the one like yours, post the link to the picture

Comment: here is a video of the cartridge disassembly ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=huxSQljCrIc

Comment: the whole cartridge may be in backward

Comment: cartridge not in backward. my system is https://assets.ajmadison.com/image/upload/c_limit,f_auto,fl_lossy.progressive,h_350,q_auto,w_500/v1/ajmadison/images/large_no_watermark/7730.jpg

Comment: and the cartridge itself is https://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/homedepotcanada/p_1000515417.jpg?$pipGallery$&id=WXQSz1&fmt=jpg&fit=constrain,1&wid=500&hei=392